# htaccess not behaving the same on different machines

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using the following rewrite code in my htaccess, but there's a problem.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ /$1.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^admin/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)/?$ /admin/$1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^user-profile/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ /user-profile.php?view=$1 [NC,L]
```

> machine A: www.website.com/admin/admin.page [doesn't works, 404] [admin.page.php works]
>
> machine B: localhost/alias/admin/admin.page [works]
>
> machine A: www.website.com/user-profile/username [works]
>
> machine B: localhost/alias/user-profile/username [doesn't works, 302] [user-profile.php?view=username works]

whats going wrong ?

(i'm using alias on one machine, and not on the other)

> machine A: apache 2.2.22, php 5.4.3 winxp pro
>
> machine B: apache 2.2.22, php 5.4.3 win7 ultimate

EDIT:

> 127.0.0.1 - - [21/Feb/2013:11:08:32 +0100] "GET /alias/user-profile/username HTTP/1.1" 302 1373
>
> 127.0.0.1 - - [21/Feb/2013:11:08:33 +0100] "GET /alias/account HTTP/1.1" 302 20
>
> 127.0.0.1 - - [21/Feb/2013:11:08:33 +0100] "GET /alias/announcements HTTP/1.1" 200 4157

Comment: What happens when you try to access those addresses?

Comment: http/1.1 302 redirect

Comment: if signed in, to the default sign-in page, and if signed out, to the default sign out page

Comment: maybe this should be migrated to some server place.

Comment: I'm not completely sure yet what you're trying to do but note that the rewrite conditions only applies to the first RewriteRule.

Comment: Try prepending all the conditions to each rule (if that's the intention)

Comment: i want from all php files the .php to be removed, that's my intention

Comment: I am concerned that `RewriteCond` only affect the `RewriteRule` that is immediately following it, that means your second and third `RewriteRule` will be executed regardless of the `RewriteCond`.

Comment: adding the same rewritecond to the other rewriterules result in the same problem..

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^admin/admin.([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)/?$ /admin/admin.$1.php [NC,L]
```

fixes the admin part, now i need to fix the profile part..

Answer (score 0):

The rewriterules shouldn't trigger for the /alias urls as your Rewriterule defines the expression as starting with admin (^admin) also, the different hosts (www.website.com and localhost) may not arrive at the same virtual host.
The issue here is more likely to be due to the differences in the urls rather than your rewrite rules.